# Finding Y's marginal distribution where joint distribution of $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1/2$ in $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < y < 4x$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am given a two-dimensional vector (X,Y) whose joint density function is as follows:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1/2$ if $0<x<$ 1 and $0<y<4x$.

I am now to find the marginal densities of X and Y. I figured that I would simply integrate either x or y out of the joint distribution.

Thus I found $f_X(x)=\int_{0}^{4x}(1/2)dy=2x$

Similarily I found $f_Y(y)=\int_{0}^{1}(1/2)dx=1/2$. However, according to the result book, the answer to $f_Y(y)$ is $1/2*(1-y/4)$.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't taken in to account the fact that $0<y<4x$ is necessary for $f_{X,Y}(x,y)\neq 0$. So, your integral for $f_Y$ should be over $x$ such that $\frac{y}{4}<x<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nicholas' answer, if you set $y/4\leq x\leq 1$, you get
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{y/4}^1 \frac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{y}{4})$$
as desired.